# Variational proof for minimum curvature of cubic splines

Tags: reference-request, approximation-theory, calculus-of-variations, interpolation, splines

**Background:** Given an increasing set of points $(x_i)_{i=0}^n \subset \mathbb [a,b]$, a cubic spline $S(x)\in C^2([a,b])$ is a piecewise cubic polynomial on each subinterval $(x_i, x_{i+1})$.

Given a set of real number $y_0, \ldots, y_n$, then if $S(x)$ is the natural [cubic spline interpolant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation), it is also the minimizer of  $\int\limits_a^b (u''(x))^2 \, dx$ over all $C^2$ functions with $u(x_i)=y_i$ for all $i$.

**Question:** I'm looking for a variational Euler-Lagrange kind of proof for theorems of this kind, i.e., how to build a $C^m$ interpolant that minimizes $\|Ku\|_2$ for some linear operator $K$.

Comment: I suspect that the property only holds for the natural cubic spline.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: in the clamped case you also have stationarity. Formally integrating by parts twice in the clamped case, with prescribed $u'$ at $x_0$ and $x_n$, gives you that the variation vanishes for piecewise cubic, $C^2$ functions that matches the data.

Answer (score 4):

See pp.87~107 of 
*Prenter, Paddy M. Splines and variational methods. Courier Corporation, 2008.* especially p.100 where "uniqueness theorem" is proved and spline is defined as minimizer to $\displaystyle{\int}_{K}[f^{(m)}(u)]^2 du$ among $C^m$ functions over a set $K=[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$. The basic technique there is to realize $\int_K (Lf)^2=\int_K (L(f-g))^2 +\int_K (Lg)^2$ where $L=D^m$ is the differentiation operator by integration by parts.

Comment: Thanks! I read the proof, and I'm glad I did. However, I was told that for a more general linear $L$ operator one can solve it using the Euler-Lagrange variational method.

Comment: You can for this one...it depends on whether you use EL method for the minimization problem or not. And what did you mean by "more general $L$"

Comment: I altered the original OP to clarify that, hopefully it worked. Do you know a reference which uses EL for this proof?

Comment: It is only possible if you know it is isomorphic to a reproducing kernel Hilbert space.

Comment: And does these cases have a thorough treatment somewhere? This is exactly the kind of information I'm looking for.

Comment: Try to read Aronszajn's seminal paper. *Aronszajn, Nachman. "Theory of reproducing kernels." Transactions of the American mathematical society 68.3 (1950): 337-404.*

Comment: I also wanted to emphasize that there is a nice RKHS approach to this problem if you are interested.

Comment: @passerby51 I missed this comment (probably because there was a global pandemic?). Can you elaborate or send a reference?